# Python optimizing arithmetic

Tags: python, math, numpy, optimization

I have fragment of code in python which take to long time with long arrays:

```
n =30000
t = range(1,n)
s = sum(t)
for i in t:
  for j in t[i:]:
    if ts-j == i*j:
      //some simple code
```

Is there any way to optimize it? I have checked that both diff and multiply took to much time. I've tried numpy but the result was worst.

To clarify: condition is fulfilled very rarely - less than 10 for sure, so it does not affect the performance at all. And it will be just simple assignemt. The problem is with the if condition and arithmetic operation with big numbers.

Comment: How can we suggest a faster way to do something if you haven't told us what you're even trying to do?

Comment: I've added clarification to problem

Comment: Basically, you've got 2 problems: 1. A new `list` is created at each iteration, because `list` slicing works this way in Python; 2. `for`-loops are slow, so replace the double loop with something faster, e.g. `itertools.combinations`. Then rewrite it functionally, e.g. map a function on the generator of `(i, j)` tuples. It's hard to recommend something more specific as you don't show desired output etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've added the [tag:numpy] tag when you're exclusively using regular Python lists rather than numpy arrays. If you did switch to using numpy arrays then there may be ways to vectorize some or all of your computation which could potentially give very large performance  benefits. It's hard to make any specific recommendations since you still haven't  properly explained what you're trying to compute.

Comment: @user2576342 which python version are you using? Also what is `ts` in the `if` condition?

Comment: What is the variable ts ?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't specify what `ts` is, we must assume that it is an integer constant.

The condition of the inner loop is `ts - j == i * j`, which is possible only when `i + 1`and `j` divide `ts`.

So you should factor `ts` and generate all factorizations `(i + 1) . j` that satisfy `1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ n`.